# PHP help with preg_match patterns

Tags: php, preg-match, design-patterns

This is the heart of my plugin that I've been painstakingly developing. Though I've ran into some trouble with the patterns..

```
<?php

$s = '
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="single2" name="single2" src="http://api.realitylapse.com/player.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" flashvars="file=http://cerium.realitylapse.com/stream/bea352a230ebd36b52dc27d874f41f5a/4e3c5eca/default/xxxxx/xxxxx-lq.mp4&amp;plugins=ltas&amp;ltas.cc=inhldvymihzxqln&amp;provider=http" height="424" width="659">

<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.xxxxx.com/player9397/player.swf?" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="provider=http&amp;file=http://www.xxxxx.com/player9397/vb.php?id=TT175YivmF4y&amp;type=video&amp;backcolor=111111&amp;frontcolor=cccccc&amp;lightcolor=DE4949&amp;stretching=fill" height="420" width="99%">

<embed src="http://www.megavideo.com/v/P5X0UOA267fb79acd04cdb29a057c3fa0066573a1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="438">    
';


$patterns = array();
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';  
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+flashvars="(.+?)["\']'; //Possible problem..
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+file=(.+?)[&]';         //
$patterns[] = '<iframe[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<iframe[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<object[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<object[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+file=(.+?)[&]';



$patterns = "#(?:" . implode("|", $patterns) . ")#si";

preg_match_all($patterns, ($s), $m);
if (!empty($m[0]))
{ 
    $edata = array();
    foreach($m[0] as $match)
    { 

//Embeds:
if (preg_match('#realitylapse.com/stream/(.+?)[&,"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:CERIUM-->\n[cerium " . $id[1] . "]";

else if (preg_match('#http&amp;file=http://www.xxxx.com/player9397/vb.php?id=(.+?)[&,"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:UNKNOWN-->\n[vb " . $id[1] . "]";

else if (preg_match('#http://www.megavideo.com/v/(.+)[&"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:MEGAVIDEO-->\n[megavideo " . $id[1] . "]";

    }

if (isset($edata[0])) {

$embeds = implode("\n", ($edata)); 

print $embeds;

}
    } 

?>
```

This outputs only:

```
[megavideo P5X0UOA267fb79acd04cdb29a057c3fa0066573a1]
```

Every other player embed I have matches. Anything that is in the flashvars area does not. That may not be the real reason. ..Whereas something like the megavideo embed does. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regexp, I would recommend using an html parser like:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can then easily read an elements attributes.

```
$html = str_get_html('<embed id="single2" height="424" width="659" flashvars="file=http://cerium.realitylapse.com/stream/bea352a230e" >');

$embed = $html->find('embed', 1);

$embed->height; // == "424"
$embed->flashvars; // == "file=http://cerium.realitylapse.com/stream/bea352a230e"
```

Comment: For example [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is an HTML parser that's enabled by default on PHP.

Comment: ..Yeah, I hear about that again and again. It probably would have been better to go with that over regexp, but it's a bit too late now. I've already learned a fair amount about the patterns, so it's not that much of an issue anymore. ..A bit surprised the parser works with it, though.